# Looking to create an iphone app with a database to save photos taken

Tags: iphone, ios, database, wiki, searchable

looking to make an iOS app where I can take a picture and then send it to a my own searchable database, website or wiki. What would be the easiest service to do this (I can do the iOS programming its just I don't know about the other side of it).

Comment: Are you asking how to write a DB to store images, or if there is an open source image db, or how to make an image db searchable?

Comment: How to write to a DB to store images and the best one to use/pointers to books/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be to use CoreData. If you don't know about CoreData, Apple has a very comprehensive set of documentation located here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Using CD, you can save the images as NSData in the persistent store, and then turn them back into images as you fetch them from the store. The most common implementation of CoreData uses SQLite as the backing store.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to set up a SQLite database and host it (I know this sounds basic but I'm learning as I go on this)?

Comment: You don't "host" it, per say, with CoreData. Setting up the database using CD takes one line of code. Setting up the tables and columns in the database is done using a GUI, and the entities you create (your tables) are mapped to real objects, to allow you to manipulate them via code. How CoreData works is the topic of many many books, so it's beyond the scope of this site to explain it top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how to answer your question without building a db for you.  If you are just looking for resources on how to build a db, check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718282/330494)